# How to subclass a superclass chosen by traits?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a template of a class (let's call it A) that should subclass one of the other classes (B or C), depending on a compile time conditional in my custom trait struct. I'm attaching a snippet that reproduces the behaviour.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class cls_template {
public:
  using method_arg_type = T;
  virtual void method(method_arg_type) = 0;
};

using A = cls_template<float>;
using B = cls_template<int>;

template<typename T>
struct traits {
  using cls = std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, A, B>;
};

//class C : public traits<float>::cls {
class C : public A {
public:
  virtual void method(method_arg_type arg) {};
};

int main() {
  A *a = new C();
}
```

If I leave it like this (hardcoding A as superclass) it all works fine. However, once I replace the class definition with a commented out line I'm getting the following error messages:

```
test.cpp:21:27: error: unknown type name 'method_arg_type'
  virtual void method(method_arg_type arg) {};
                      ^
test.cpp:25:10: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'A *'
  (aka 'cls_template<float> *') with an rvalue of type 'C *'
  A *a = new C();
     ^   ~~~~~~~
```

Why is `method_arg_type` no longer defined? Why is `C` no longer recognised  as subclass of `A`? I've found out that if `traits` aren't a template (if I just hardcode a type into the struct), it all works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to derive from `traits<float>::cls` which is of type `std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, A, B>`. It's neither `A` nor `B`, it's a specialization of the `conditional` template. Either derive from `::type` of it, which will work as you expected, or use `conditional_t` (C++14).

```
class C : public traits<float>::cls::type { // ok
                                   ^^^^^^
public:
  virtual void method(method_arg_type arg) {};
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nPbwySR6WRJ8HxlU)

```
template<typename T>
struct traits {
  using cls = std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, A, B>;
                              ^^
  // above is C++14, in C++11 you'd have to write
  // using cls = typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, A, B>::type;
};

class C : public traits<float>::cls { // also ok
public:
  virtual void method(method_arg_type arg) {};
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/U7PtVIJmm4KMyjHs)

Comment: Additionally `using cls = typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, A, B>::type;` can be used  but `std::conditional_t` looks a lot better. +1

Comment: Ugh, yeah you've got the type in the example, but unfortunately it's not the issue I'm having in my real code. I'll try to isolate another snippet.